# Could JS object hashing explain this, and what can I do about it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, hash

I've spent a couple of hours wondering why (with lots of experiments) a simple optimization to use less memory has caused a slowdown in a block of code that was not touched. Basically I've gone from working with long strings to short strings. That particular block of code is about 33% slower, according to my profiling. (It is very noticeable in the unit test, but won't matter in production; my effort is just to try and understand why.)

The code boils down to:

```
const cnts = new FreqCounts()
for (const id of myArray)cnts.inc(id)
```

Using this class:

```
class FreqCounts {
  constructor () {
    this.d = {}
  }

  inc (v) {
    if (this.d[v]) this.d[v]++
    else this.d[v] = 1
  }
}
```

So, before, myArray looked something like this:

```
const myArray = [
  '黄砂（こうさ、おうさ、黄沙とも）とは、特に中国を中心とした東アジア内陸部の砂漠または乾燥地域の砂塵が、強風を伴う砂塵嵐（砂嵐）などによって上空に巻き上げられ、春を中心に東アジアなどの広範囲に飛散し、地上に降り注ぐ気象現象。あるいは、この現象で飛散した砂自体のことである。',
  //...usually 5 to 50 more entries here
  '気象現象としての黄砂は、砂塵の元になる土壌の状態、砂塵を運ぶ気流など、大地や大気の条件が整うと、発生すると考えられている。',
]
```

And now it either looks like this:

```
const myArray = [
  1234,
  //...
  77,
]
```

Or like this:

```
const myArray = [
  '1234',
  //...
  '77',
]
```

The second way should be saving the implicit number to string conversion, yet turned out to be even slower.

Having run out of logical explanations, the only idea I have left is that, because those strings end up as keys in an object, that they all end up hashing to the same hashcode and I get lots of collisions. Does that sound plausible?

(By the way, only evaluated with Node 8.16; the slowdown was not visible when working with 2,000 sentences, but was with 32,000, so getting a fully reproducible example might be tricky.)

**BACKGROUND**

Previously each string was repeated maybe 100 times; that became very noticeable when serializing the object to disk. So I'm simply putting them in a lookup table (which also gets saved):

```
const lookup = []
...
const id = lookup.length  //If storing number
//const id = '' + lookup.length  //If storing string
lookup.push(s)
...
myArray.push(id)
```

This has achieved the memory goal: the disk file with realistic data reduced from 500KB to 50KB. But, as I said above, I didn't expect it to slow down my unit tests.

Is there a way to continue to store lookup table indices, but not get hash collisions? (If that is what the problem is.)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? how are you calculating ids? can you show a complete code example?

Comment: could you include a snippet that shows your setup and reproduces the problem. Here are way too many tiny screws and switches that could cause a significant difference